# Using EndNote to export BibTeX to clipboard?

Tags: bibtex, sharelatex

In EndNote, is there a way to export BibTex as *plain text* to the clipboard?

I'm using Sharelatex+ Endnote to work on my thesis. There's only one .bib file to organize all my references. So the method I put a new reference into this .bib file is:

copy the corresponding BibTex then append in the .bib file, but I only find the way to export the BibTex as a single file in EndNote. What I need is frequently append single BibTex. Exporting file then copy again doesn't make sense here.

I'm new here, I don't know if I should find another way to organize my reference in sharelatex... or ..?[image]

Comment: This question is borderline off-topic for this site, it's more an issue with Endnote than with LaTeX/BibTeX. However, you might try to select the new reference, export only that to a file (using the checkbox as shown at the bottom of your screenshot), and then combine https://superuser.com/questions/342545/copy-content-of-txt-file-without-opening-it with https://superuser.com/questions/468662/how-to-monitor-a-folder-for-changes-and-execute-a-command-if-it-does-on-window.

Comment: More than off-topic, is unclear for me. If you are working with LaTeX and a bibtex file, why the hell are you using EndNote?

Comment: As I said, probably made you confused, I need to reference the articles in BibTex style frequently, add them to my bibtex file in sharelatex.